# Assets with different languages

Tags: java, android, resources, assets

I know that it is possible to have different languages in the `res/values-ISOCode` direcotry. Is this possible for xml files in the `assets` directory as well? How would the folder structure have to look?

Comment: I have some `help-de.htm`, `help-en.htm` and so on in my `assets/help` folder. I simply choose the right one basing on the current locale. Each of them is a translated version of the app guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible for xml files in the assets directory as well?

Yes and no.

Yes, you can put whatever files you want into `assets/`, in whatever languages you want.

No, insofar as Android does not automatically load a specific asset based on language. You would have to do that yourself (e.g., look up the language via `Locale`, then generate the right directory name based on that language). Android only loads things from different directories based on configuration for resources, not assets.

> How would the folder structure have to look?

Whatever your generate-a-directory-name-based-on-language algorithm would require.